# NET 6 Core using Pages posting to a custom method

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, web

Using the NET 6 core application with **Pages**.

Right out of the box the project has the following "code behind"

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    // This is this the new code 
    public void MyCustomMethod()
    {
        var debug = "Stop Here debug break point";
    }
}
```

The front end has the following:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
   <form action="MyCustomMethod" method="get">
       <input type="submit" />
   </form>
</div>
```

Unable to **GET** or **POST** to the custom method (MyCustomMethod) in the **NET 6 CORE using PAGES**.

It could be a dumb question by I tried to google for the past 2 hours and can not find anything related to what I am doing. Please help.

Trying to use a simple form to get or post to the "code behind". When page load I do see a debug going into OnGet() method which it should do but clicking on a button in a form it never makes it into MyCustomMethod().

Thank you.

Did the following change to a code:

```
    [HttpPost] // Second run added this because it was still not working
    public void OnPostMyCustomMethod()
    {
        var debug = "Stop Here debug break point";
    }

Front page
    <form action="MyCustomMethod" method="post">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Still unable access:

[Debug Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYUcP.png)

Comment: Rename the method in codebehind to: `OnPostMyCustomMethod()`. Then it should work. - or `OnGetMyCustomMethod()`, if you want get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor Pages includes a feature called "named handler methods". This feature enables you to specify multiple methods that can be executed for a single verb.

If you have set the OnPostMyCustomMethod or MyCustomMethod in the backend codes, you should use this url "https://localhost:7086/?handler=MyCustomMethod" to access it.

More details, you could refer to below example:

```
  <form asp-page-handler="MyCustomMethod"   method="post">
       <input type="submit" />
   </form>
```

Comment: Just started learning "Razor Pages includes a feature called 'named handler methods'". It works now.

Comment: Hi, I tried to do the same using Axios to call my razor pages method and is not get executed. I get a 400 Bad Request.  In my Axios Im calling:

 axios.post('/Account/Login?handler=MyCustomMethod', { payload: "abc" })
                .then(function (response) {
                   
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // Handle the error response
                });

And in my Login page I have:

  public IActionResult OnPostMyCustomMethod(string payload)
        {
            return new JsonResult(true);
        }
Any clue?